# Selenium browsermobproxy makes all webs insecure

Tags: java, selenium, browsermob

I have tried to add this to the driver to avoid the problem

```
DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_SSL_CERTS, true);
desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.ACCEPT_INSECURE_CERTS, true);
```

But one time the browser mob is set up all the webs are insecure.

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Comment: How do you set up proxy?

Comment: Following this tutorial https://www.swtestacademy.com/webdriver-browsermob-proxy/